# Getting attributes from uploading image file in odoo

Tags: image, upload, attributes, odoo

In a custom module I'm uploading an image file to the database. Now I want to get some attribtues from the upload file, while the image file is uploading to odoo and save this attributes in the database. To get the filename I use following code in the form.view:

```
<field name="image" filename="name"/>
```

With the parameter filename="name" the filename from the image file is saved into the database field name. This works fine.

My question is now, how can I get other attributes from the uploading image file? For example I want to get the recording date, resolution, image size ... Has anybody an idea how to get this attributes from the uploding image file to save this information in the database record?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to this should work:

```
import PIL 
from StringIO import StringIO


class SomeModelWithImage(models.Model):
    image = fields.Image(required=True)
    name = fields.Char()
    size = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_image_details')
    camera_maker = fields.Char(compute='_compute_image_details')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('image')
    def _compute_image_details(self):
        image_content = self.image.decode('base64')

        # File size
        self.size = len(self.image_content)

        # Camera make and model from EXIF tags
        image = PIL.Image.open(StringIO(image_content))
        exif_tags = image._getexif()

        # 0x010f is a numeric code for the "make" exif field
        # You can find a list of fields here: exiv2.org/tags.html
        self.camera_maker = exif_tags.get(0x010f)
```

This creates two additional fields - `size` and `camera_maker`, which are automatically populated when the `image` field is set. The camera maker information is taken from image's EXIF tags. You can see other possible EXIF tags under [exiv2.org/tags.html](http://exiv2.org/tags.html). You should note that there is no requirement for an image to have any tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. This helps a lot. Two additions, that this works. To get the StringIO add "from StringIO import StringIO" at the beginning and change img to image.

Comment: Some additions: 1. python3 using 'from io import StringIO'; 2. this example is to retrieve data from image field. If we want to read image raw data from 'self.datas', we need to change StringIO to BytesIO;

Answer (score -1):

You can Inherit the **"ir.attachment"** and create your metadata fields and store this detail in model and you can try to find the detail by this code.

The Image File Get in Encoded Format so You can decode64 throw convert the file and get the image and get the metadata of image.

```html
import os
import time
from stat import *  # ST_SIZE etc

try:
    st = os.stat('1.png')
except IOError:
    print "failed to get information about", file
else:
    print "file size:", st[ST_SIZE]
    print "file modified:", time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME]))
```

[This](http://effbot.org/zone/python-fileinfo.htm) Refrence Link Help You....

May be other Solution but that time not found so you can try to this code..